# How to upgrade php4.x.x to php5.x.x

Tags: php

I want to upgrade php4 to php5 in server.because i am installing TCExam on server, a test assessment spftware runs on php5.3.1 version but version of php onserver is 4.x.x .will it affect the existing project .if not can you explain me how to upgrade the php version on server.

Comment: It depends on the code of the existing projects. Best way is to try it, you can always revert back to your original PHP version.

Comment: Are you using a web host or a VPS/Dedicated?

Comment: StackExchange sites are not for "how to" questions. If you attempt to do this and have issues then come back and ask us specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

There's a complete guide on how to upgrade php4 code to php5 here:

http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.php

To upgrade your server software, re-install php as needed. On Windows, this means downloading the executable and follow the steps...